# How do I build a mono from a callable that would return a mono?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have this code that would call reactive Spring Redis Template to store some data I am stuck at the point of the switchIfEmpty where I want to create a new entry and store it and return the result.

```
    public Mono<SecretKey> secretKey(String jti, int expiresInSeconds) {

        final var urlDecoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();
        var ops = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
        return ops.getAndExpire(simpleAuthServiceProperties + ":::symmetricKeys:::"+ jti, Duration.ofSeconds(expiresInSeconds))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    final var secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
                    final var encoded = secretKey.getEncoded();
                    final var e = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encoded);
                    var x = ops.setIfAbsent(simpleAuthServiceProperties + ":::symmetricKeys:::"+ jti, e, Duration.ofSeconds(expiresInSeconds))
                            .flatMap(result -> {
                                if (result) {
                                    return Mono.just(e);
                                } else {
                                    return Mono.error(IllegalStateException::new);
                                }
                            });
                    return x;
                }))
                .map(urlDecoder::decode)
                .map(bytes->
                    new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES")
                );
    }
```

I got to the point of `x` which gives me a `Mono<String>` but I need the fromCallable to return a `String`

I am thinking if I just change `switchIfEmpty` to something else...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) Mono.fromCallable() accepts `Callable<? extends T>`, not `Callable<? extends Mono<? extends T>>`, so it is not a surprise that you get `Mono<Mono<...>>` as result.

You can try [Mono.defer()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of Mono.fromCallable().